# Tkinter Quiz doesn't end when it reaches 10

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

```
def confirmAnswer(self):
        answer = self.enterAnswer.get() #Obtains what the user has typed into the textbox.
        if answer == self.correctAnswer: #Checks the answer submitted compares to correct answer.
            self.quizScore += 1 # Adds one to score.
            ms.showinfo(title='Correct', message='Correct')
            #self.Qn = self.Qn + 1# This changes to the next question.

            if x == 10:# Question number is one above the number of questions else last question wont work. Ends when it hits 11 as 10 questions.
                ms.showinfo(title="End of test", message = "This is the end of the test. You scored")
            else:
                self.update_question() # Gets next question

        else:
            ms.showwarning(title='Incorrect', message='Incorrect')
            if x == 10:# Question number is one above the number of questions else last question wont work. Ends when it hits 11 as 10 questions.
                ms.showinfo(title="End of test", message = "This is the end of the test. You scored")
            else:
                self.update_question()
                global num
                num = randint(1,10)
```

Quiz should end when it reaches question 10 but proceeds to question 11, 12 etc. I only have 10 questions in the SQL database I call them from but just repeats each question twice.

```
def update_question(self):
        # Get new question
        global num
        num = randint(1, 10)
        query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE [qnumber] =?"
        c.execute(query,(num,))
        row = c.fetchone()

        self.question['text'] = row[1]

        self.answer1['text'] = row[2]
        self.answer2['text'] = row[3]
        self.answer3['text'] = row[4]
        self.answer4['text'] = row[5]

        self.correctAnswer = row[6]
```

This is the piece of code that updates the questions.

```
global x
x = IntVar()
x.set(1)
def add():
    x.set(x.get()+1)

self.recordNum = Label(self.quizf, textvariable=x)
self.recordNum.pack()

self.enterAnswer = Entry(self.quizf)
self.Submit = Button(self.quizf, text = 'submit', command=lambda:[self.confirmAnswer(),add()])
```

This piece of code is how the question number updates which is carried out when pressing the submit button. When x reaches 10 it should end the code but continues adding 1.

Comment: What have you done to debug this?

Comment: I tried changing the variable, but didn’t know what to do after that, but that answer has fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x is declared as an IntVar, to retrieve its value, you should use its method 'get' as :

```
if x.get() == 10:
    # DO SOMETHING
else:
    # DO SOMETHING ELSE
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Didn’t think it would be that simple